# Зачем при автоматическом строительстве switch добавляется default?

Tags: c#, switch, enum

Когда автоматически строится `switch` на основе `enum`, почему добавляется `default` ?

Ведь других вариантов быть не может кроме как значений `enum`.

Или есть какие-то подводные камни ?

Comment: Если вы позже добавите в enum значение, default: пригодится.

Comment: Ну почеу не может, может... `var myEnumResult = (MySuperEnum)100;`, значения 100 в тестовом enum условно нет, вот и получаете default. [Пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w3vhGe).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну да, впихнуть что угодно можно, я просто преполагал что использовать надо по именам. Отлично замечание от Станислава, что может быть добавление, спасибо всем!